# JQM Accordion gets highlights on long press.

Tags: jquery-mobile, accordion

I am new to Jquery Mobile, and getting a strange behaviour. When I long press any of my item  accordion it get highlight and remain highlighted even though I switch to other accordion item. here how it is looking [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgks1.png)

Comment: Please post your code/markup, jqm and jquery versions, and if possible, a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.